# How to efficiently count unique (numeric) column vectors of a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

```
foo <- data.table(x = 1:5/sum(1:5),
                  y = (-4):0/sum((-4):0),
                 z1 = 2:6/sum(2:6),
                 z2 = 2:6/sum(2:6))
```

Suppose I have the `foo` data table (as specified above):

```
            x   y   z1   z2
1: 0.06666667 0.4 0.10 0.10
2: 0.13333333 0.3 0.15 0.15
3: 0.20000000 0.2 0.20 0.20
4: 0.26666667 0.1 0.25 0.25
5: 0.33333333 0.0 0.30 0.30
```

How to efficiently count unique columns? In this case only 3.

Please assume that in general:

1. `foo` is always a data table and not a matrix; though the columns are always numeric.
2. `foo` in reality is big, nrow > 20k and ncol > 100

Is it possible to do this without making extra copies of the data?

My current approach is to `apply` over columns with `paste` to get a single value for each column and then do `length(unique(.))` on the result...

Is there any magic with `data.table::transpose()`, `data.table::uniqueN`, and maybe some other friends?

Comment: A quick optimization: `uniqueN` is an exported function, so use that instead of `length(unique())`.

Comment: Please don't benchmark on micro datasets. microseconds benchmarks won't tell you anything on how it would scale on a real data set.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: I see...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another possibility:

```
length(unique(as.list(foo)))
```

Which gives the expected result:

> ```
> > length(unique(as.list(foo)))
> [1] 3
> ```

NOTE: the use of `length(unique())` is necessary as `uniqueN()` will return an error.

Per the comment of @Ryan, you can also do:

```
length(unique.default(foo))
```

---

With regard to speed, both methods are comparable (when measured on a larger dataset of 5M rows):

> ```
> > fooLarge <- foo[rep(1:nrow(foo),1e6)]
> > microbenchmark(length(unique.default(fooLarge)), length(unique(as.list(fooLarge))))
> Unit: milliseconds
>                               expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
>   length(unique.default(fooLarge)) 94.0433 94.56920 95.24076 95.01492 95.67131 103.15433   100   a
>  length(unique(as.list(fooLarge))) 94.0254 94.68187 95.17648 95.02672 95.49857  99.19411   100   a
> ```

---

If you want to retain only the unique columns, you could use:

```
# option 1
cols <- !duplicated(as.list(foo))
foo[, ..cols]

# option 2 (doesn't retain the column names)
as.data.table(unique.default(foo))
```

which gives (output option 1 shown):

> ```
>             x   y   z1
> 1: 0.06666667 0.4 0.10
> 2: 0.13333333 0.3 0.15
> 3: 0.20000000 0.2 0.20
> 4: 0.26666667 0.1 0.25
> 5: 0.33333333 0.0 0.30
> ```

Comment: Does `as.list` make a copy? If so, is it possible to call the `list` method of `unique` on a `data.table` (or `data.frame`)?

Comment: As far as I know there is no `list`-method for `unique`, see also `methods('unique')`.

Comment: @Jaap: Great, neat answer. Is it possible to control the numeric tolerance of the comparisons?

Comment: Looking at `methods('unique')`, you can do `length(unique.default(foo))` to avoid `as.list`. Which would only be worth doing if as.list creates a copy, which I'm not sure of.

Comment: @Ryan: `length(unique.default(foo))` seems to be quite fast.

Comment: @Ryan Thx, included that option as well. I'm not sure whether `as.list` makes a copy, but I suspect it does as do the other `as.*`-functions AFAIK.

Comment: @plant It should be possible, but then you'll have to write your own function with  `all.equal` which has a tolerance parameter.

Comment: @plant I've included a benchmark on a large dataset as well. There is not much of a difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

transpose and check for non-duplicates

```
ncol( foo[ , which( !duplicated( t( foo ) ) ), with = FALSE ])

3
```

Comment: `t( foo )` creates a copy of `foo` in memory temporarily, no?

Comment: and is the `which` really needed?

Comment: according to microbenchmark, the 'which' seems to (marginally) speed things up.. (361 us versus 379 us) not sure why...

Answer (score 1):

Another method which may be faster if you expect a large number of duplicates:

```
n_unique_cols <- function(foo) {
  K <- seq_along(foo)
  for (j in seq_along(foo)) {
    if (j %in% K) {
      foo_j <- .subset2(foo, j)
      for (k in K) {
        if (j < k) {
          foo_k <- .subset2(foo, k)
          if (foo_j[1] == foo_k[1] && identical(foo_j, foo_k)) {
            K <- K[K != k]
          }
          rm(foo_k)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  length(K)
}
```

Timings:

```
library(data.table)
create_foo <- function(row, col) {
  foo <- data.table(x = rnorm(row), 
                    y = seq_len(row) - 2L)

  set.seed(1)
  for (k in seq_len(col %/% 2L)) {
    foo[, (paste0('x', k)) := x + sample(-4:4, size = 1)]
    foo[, (paste0('y', k)) := y + sample(-2:2, size = 1)]
  }
  foo
}

library(bench)
res <- 
  press(rows = c(1e5, 1e6, 1e7), 
        cols = c(10, 50, 100), 
        {

          foorc <- create_foo(rows, cols)
          bench::mark(n_unique_cols(foorc), 
                      length(unique(as.list(foorc))))
        })
plot(res)
```

For this family of data, this function is twice as fast, but its memory consumption grows faster than `unique(as.list(.))`.

[image]